# breakpoint effect in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner in Bootstrap, just a question on the following code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-lg-4 border">One</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 border">Two</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 border">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if I size my browser window to small size which doesn't qualify for the lg breakpoint, you can see that those three elements stack each other.
But if I remove the breakpoint , just like:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="border">One</div>
    <div class="border">Two</div>
    <div class="border">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

those three elements are like inline elements instead of stacking each other, why? since it is actually the same code with col-lg-4 as long as I stay in the small size of window, so the lg breakpoint hasn't been trigger.

Comment: what is you are actual need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the relevant CSS code from bootstrap (I commented the irrelevant parts)

```
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*margin-right: -15px;*/
    /*margin-left: -15px;*/
}

/*.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, */
.col-lg-4,
/*.col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto */ {
    /*position: relative;*/
    width: 100%;
    /*min-height: 1px;*/
    /*padding-right: 15px;*/
    /*padding-left: 15px;*/
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-lg-4 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
}
```

You see:
`.row` has `display: flex`. Every direct child element of `.row` is a flex item with the [default value for `flex-basis` of `auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-basis). A `auto` flex item takes only as much space as it needs (if no width is given)
`.col-lg-4` has always a width of 100%, but on large screens (>= 992px) it get's a `flex-basis` of `33.333333%` (one third).

If you remove the `col-lg-4` class, those elements are still flex items with no `flex-basis` set hence having implicit `flex-basis: auto`

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if I want those three elements stack each other all the time. so I have to add 'sth' like `<div class="col-...-...">`, isn't that a little bit strange?

Comment: @amjad No it's not strange. The `row` class is intended to act so. If you use `row`, the child elements should be `col-*`

Answer (score 3):

It's because the Bootstrap row is `display:flex`, and the default flexbox direction is `flex-direction:row`. If you remove the `.row` you'll see the inner divs stack as expected.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="border">
        <div class="border">One</div>
        <div class="border">Two</div>
        <div class="border">Three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/H2y9xDXLv8

---

Also note, [the `.row` should only be used to contain grid columns (`.col*`)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one thing I still don't get is, why a breakpoint in lg size like `col-lg-4` can also make those three items stack each other in sm? lg does't apply in small window?

Comment: so  adding lg should not affect the small window, but why it did? if you add `col-lg-4`, in the small size of window, those three element will stack each other? because according to what you said, the flexbox direction is still `flex-direction:row`

Comment: Inspect your col element in your browsers developer tools. Every `.col-***` element has a default width of `100%`

Comment: I don't understand your question. `col-lg-4` means 3 columns in a row on lg and larger (screen width greater than 992px). On screen widths less than 992px the columns stack vertically.. therefore, lg doesn't effect the smaller screen widths!

Comment: @Zim OK, let me put it n this way: with nothing in the class, those 3 elements are like inline  elements. With col-lg-4 in the class and when in small size, those 3 stack each other, but in small size, col-lg-4 doesn't apply at all, so it is like nothing in the class, so it is supposed to be inline elements again, but why they stack each other?

Comment: Because all `col*` have a default width of 100%. What is your actual problem/question? What are you trying to accomplish? You should read [how the grid works](https://uxplanet.org/how-the-bootstrap-4-grid-works-a1b04703a3b7)

Comment: @Zim    but I didn't code like `<div class="col col-lg-4">`, so then lg doesn't apply, it is like  `<div class="">` for small window?

Comment: It doesn't matter! `col-lg-4` has a default width of 100% on screen widths less than 992px. Look at the comment from @yunzen

Comment: @Zim  sorry, it is making me more confused, isn't `.col-lg-x` apply(kick in) when screen widths more than 992px, why you say less than 992px?

Comment: @yunzen    but `.col-lg-x` doesn't apply in small window, so it is like `<div class="">`?

Comment: Part of `.col-lg-x` does. Carefully look at the bootstrap CSS. If you have something like this `body { background: yellow;} @media (max-width: 800px) { body { background: lightgreen; } }` The first part of body will always work and the second part only on small width

Answer (score -1):

The Bootstrap grid system has five classes:

```
.col- (extra small devices - screen width less than 576px)
.col-sm- (small devices - screen width equal to or greater than 576px)
.col-md- (medium devices - screen width equal to or greater than 768px)
.col-lg- (large devices - screen width equal to or greater than 992px)
.col-xl- (xlarge devices - screen width equal to or greater than 1200px)
```

They automatically trigger with sizes change

[Boostrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Answer (score -1):

Try putting instead of `col-lg-4` with `col-xs-12`. This will make your "divs" with this class stay stacked.

Hope this can help you.